# cannot deploy to heroku because the key with fingerprint is not authorised

Tags: git, deployment, heroku, ssh-keys, fingerprint

I have one git repository and I want to have 2 heroku apps from the single repo - production and staging. For the production app, i'm the collaborator (not the owner). For the staging, I would like to be the owner.

I have done the following in the command line:

```
heroku create app-staging-name
git remote add staging git-repo-address-given
git push staging master
```

it gives me the error:

```
!  Your key with fingerprint xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx is not authorized to access app-staging-name. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly.
```

I have also [added a new SSH key to heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/keys). How can I deploy 2 heroku apps from the same git repo with no fingerprint conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i had to use these steps to clear out heroku keys and then create one and add it.

```
heroku keys:clear
ssh-keygen -t rsa # put the new name as /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_appname
heroku keys:add
```